# TFS / Visual Studio 2015 does not trigger a pending add action for added files

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

Since a couple of weeks we've been having strange issues happening within our TFS instance.

for some unknown reason whenever we try to add a new or existing file to a solution / project, visual studio only detects a change in the project file to add the reference to the newly added file but ignores the "physical" file itself.

In the pending changes we only see a change on the *.proj file and that's it.

It looks like this:

[image: Adding a new file]

[image: added view]

[image: check-out warning on project file]

[image: solution explorer after the add]

[image: Team Explorer - Pending Changes after the add]

*(i know the screenshots are different projects, but when i was recreating the error for the images it suddenly went alright in the first project so i tried another).*

The file does not appear in the excluded list nor does it appear in the detected changes.

From what i've found online is that it could be a binding issue. So things i tried are the following:

- Deleting and creating a new local workspace
- unbinding the solution and every project, Check this in, add the binding again and lastly checking this change again back in.

The issue occurs on existing projects which have been under source control for atleast a week or more.

The issue occurs at multiple developers / machines and I don't seem to be able to find a correlation on when this happens. Sometimes when I add a file my colleague can not add it then some other time it does not work for both of us. Another scenario is that projects work perfectly fine one day then another day they don't

We have tried this on similar and different projects in TFS. A Workaround is available by manually adding the missing files by interface or cmdprompt but it worked before and it easy to miss a file because of this.

We are running TFS Server 2015 onprem on a Windows Server 2012 R2 using the default SQLExpress instance it came with. Our Visual Studio edition is 2015 Community Edition with SQL Server tools enabled on them (latest stable release).

Edit: This might be something but can also be nothing. When attempting another file just ago I had the Team Explorer open and I saw the added file in the pending changes and it suddenly disappeared changing to the state i describe in this post.

Hoping someone has a suggestion to find the cause and a solution for this issue.

Comment: Did this happen with that specific project or all the new created project ?

Comment: I haven't created any new projects. I should have made that more clear. These are all existing projects and the issues occur on these existing projects.

Comment: It's really weird(usually unbinding and binding will solve it), and the issue seems to be randomly. Things like this  is the most difficult to handle. According to your edit `When attempting another file just ago I had the Team Explorer open and I saw the added file in the pending changes and it suddenly disappeared` . I was wondering if your network is stability. You can check if your solution is online. If it's, `file > Source Control > Go Online`

Comment: And you can try to [clear tfs and vs cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/),  see if this could be  helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Patrick. Do you perhaps have a screenshot to where i can find the option to go online? When i check the path you mentioned i do not find the option to go online. Nor do i see the option amongst any other when checking the File -> Source Control option. I have tried while having either solution / project or a file selected and going to the menu option.

Comment: I will read the other article you mentioned because it has some side-affects to it. And to come back to the network stability possibility you mentioned i can't recall a moment where we have lost a connection to the server as a whole so could a packet hickup upon checking out be a possibility and can it cause a binding to go bad after that?

Comment: This means your solution is online. That's not the root cause. For `can it cause a binding to go bad after that? `  not sure about this, but you could go through it on your TFS server to check whether there are some related error info in logs or server event log.  Sometimes good,sometimes bad and your account is good, his account is not good. A big possibility is related to the server. Change local mapping may not solve the problem.

Comment: Reminds me a little of an overzealous .gitignore file behavior. Is it possible someone somehow configured the repo to ignore files of type *.sql?

Comment: @PeterSchott  You could use `.tfignore` to achieve this behave.Details you can refer  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control